# React - How can the parent know which children was clicked?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component, that I want to make re-usable and use in multiple pages in my app, that takes a number of children (multiple instances of the same component).
Imagine `react-select`. In the most basic usage, you provide a list of `options` a selected `value` and an `onChange` function. All of these are provided as props of `Select`.

I want to implement something somewhat similar, but that takes the "options" as children elements instead of a prop, and the rest as props of the parent.

Right now I have something this:

```js
enum Children {
  first = "first",
  second = "second",
  // ...
}

const [child, setChild] = useState(Children.first)

<ChildrenSelect>
  <Child
    selected={child === Children.first}
    onClick={() => setChild(Children.first)}
  />
  <Child
    selected={child === Children.second}
    onClick={() => setChild(Children.second)}
    // more props 
  />
  {/* ... potentially more children */}
</ChildrenSelect>
```

Here I have the state of which `child` is selected managed by the outermost component.
I would like to move the `selected` and `onClick` props from the children to the `ChildrenSelect` component, in order to have more compact children:

```js
const childClickHandler = (c: Children) => setChild(c);

<ChildrenSelect
  selected={child} //: Children
  onChildClick={childClickHandler} //: (c: Children) => void
>
  <Child id={Children.first} />
  <Child id={Children.second} />
  {/* ... potentially more children */}
</ChildrenSelect>
```

**But how does the `ChildrenSelect` component know which `Child` was clicked?**

---

**EDIT: I'm nearly there!**

Based on [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/08/react-children-iteration-methods/) and [this](https://medium.com/@cristiansima/typescript-ing-react-cloneelement-or-how-to-type-a-child-element-with-props-injected-by-the-parent-73b6ad485f8b) I managed something that looks close to the desired solution.

**You can loop trough `children` inside the `ChildrenSelect` component and have the parent modify the children's props.**

So the code for the `ChildrenSelect` component would be something like this:

```
// ChildrenSelect
import React, { Children, BaseHTMLAttributes, FC, cloneElement, ReactElement } from "react";

type Props = {
  // ChildrenSelectspecific props
} & BaseHTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>;

export const ChildrenSelect: FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const childrenArray = Children.toArray(children);

  const handleChildClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  return (
    <div className="children-select">
      <div>{/* other parent stuff */}</div>
      {Children.map(childrenArray, (child, i) => {
        console.log("child is", child);
        return cloneElement(child as ReactElement<ChildComponentProps>, {
          onClick: handleChildClick,
          text: `modified child ${i}`,
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the DevTools I can see that the new props have been set:

```
props
  onClick: ƒ handleChildClick() {}
  text: "modified child 0"
```

But nothing gets printed when I click on any of the children, which makes think that `handleChildClick` is not being called.

Comment: im not sure if i understand ur question correct but why u dont add children into a array and loop them, give them so a id based on a loop and render them into Parent?  So u should, can read in the click handler the id of the child and know which ones was clicked.

Comment: Why not give index to your chidren, so you can call the same method and pass index in.

Comment: and btw when u work with children u can pass a functions over props so  so can send "data" from child to mother and reverse over props

Comment: @StefanBD I would have to create an object with all the props of a `Child`, put those objects for all children into an array and then map each entry of the array to a `Child` component. I don't think that improves much from my second solution. Actually I think it's more confusing.

Comment: I think your most recent solution is making this more difficult than necessary. I suggest you read about `useEffect()`. You can use this to change a value in the children which then the parent can detect and render what it wants.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice perhaps while trying to make the examples simple, I didn't explain well what I want. I'm sorry about that. Let me try to make the examples clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the new props have been set right, you need to add each prop to the `Child` component to make it work.

```js
// Child.tsx
export const Child = (props) => {
 const { onClick, text } = props;

 return (
  <div {...props}
  // or
  <div onClick={onClick} text={text}
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

based on my comment when i understand ur question correct.

```
function handler(e)=>{

console.log("clicked "+e.target.id) //maybe its e.currentTarget.id
}

let childArr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
childArr.push(  <Child key={"child"+i} id={"child"+i} onClick=(e => handler(e)) />);
}

<Parent
  selected={child} // : Children
  onChildClick={childClickHandler} // : (c: Children) => void
>
{childArr}
</Parent>
```

Comment: Again, that's basically what I have in the second solution. Shorter but more confusing. Plus it doesn't account for the fact that `Child` has more props.

Comment: Maybe refs and queryselector is what u want ? https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-document-queryselector, your wish sounds like stuff we did with jQuery , hook onclick for everything in the last 10 years.

Comment: Another Idea but more theoretical, if the parent have a higher zIndex than the children so maybe u can trigger with the onclick on this the real target.

Comment: @StefanDB thanks. I usually try to avoid refs unless their really necessary, but I'll have a look.

Comment: The question is also what do u want, u don't need the ref if u want trigger only a click so u should easily set the event listener of queryselector  to a prop like regex the id.  for example: document.querySelectorAll("[id^='abc']") trigger also element with id abc1, abc2

Comment: I think I found an answer. I'm just fighting with Typescript (love it, but it's annoying sometimes) to make it work and I'll post it as soon as I see that it works. You can loop through children inside the Parent and modify the children's props. I got it from here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/08/react-children-iteration-methods/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change

```
onClick={firstChildClickHandler()}
```

to

```
onClick={childClickHandler}
```

The difference here is the first one calls the function and gets the return value, which then becomes the onclick handler. The second one sets the onlcick handler directly as the function, which is what you want.

Second, change the clickhandleer to take a parameter:

```
const childClickHandler = (e) = {/* do stuff */}
```

Now you can access the item that was clicked on with `e.target`.

You can take this even further and add whatever parameters you want to `childClickHandler`. Then in the `Child` component, you call the `onClick` with the appropriate parameters for that particular child.

Comment: when i understand him correct he dont want this he want the handler in the parent like u have with Selects and not in the childrens

Comment: "First of all", that was typo, thanks for pointing out. Second, that seems to be the same as I have in the second block of code.

Comment: @StefanBD exactly.

Comment: @MarcoCastanho If I understand correctly, you want to set the state in the parent which child was selected, is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly. I want the parent to be something like `react-select`, where you have `options`, a selected `value` and an `onChange` method, except I want may "options" to be elements passed as children and the selected `value` to be the id of whichever child is selected.